# ¿De dónde viene la palabra "mesingo"?

Tags: etimología, españa, adjetivos, palabras-raras

En el [Diccionario de la lengua](https://dle.rae.es/mesingo) de la RAE se recoge desde 1925 hasta la actualidad la palabra **mesingo** como:

> 1. adj. *Sal.* Débil, delicado.
> 2. adj. *Sal.* melindroso.

¿Cuál es el origen de esta palabra, aparentemente específica de Salamanca (no aparece en los diccionario etimológicos de Corominas, Echegaray o Mondau)?

Comment: En el fichero general de la RAE hay tan solo 5 fichas acerca de la palabra y ninguna habla de su posible origen.

Comment: I'm sorry, I apologize for misunderstanding. I thought "¿De dónde viene la palabra “mesingo”?" meant: "Where does the word "mesingo" come from?"

Comment: @Edna, actually it does mean that, but the body of the question clarifies they're after the etymology with "What is the origin of this word" and the "etimología" tag.

Comment: @sonia ¿Dónde has visto la palabra?

Answer (score 1):

**Cuestión**: ¿De dónde viene la palabra "mesingo"?

Tiene varias acepciones  a parte de las que aparece en la RAE Débil, delicado, melindroso, vanidoso....también; Que afecta demasiada delicadeza, melindroso.

---

La verdad es que no ha sido fácil de entender, ya no lo que significaba, "Mesingo", sino como evolucionó, a quien iba dirigido y por qué. No puedo  exponer todo el estudio completo, ya que llevaría casi un librito completo, aunque intentare ajustar y resumir.

Salamanca por su Universidad ha sido tradicional como seña de identidad en el lenguaje y en el encuentro de la ciudad con el léxico y su gente. De esta mezcla estudiantil, agrícola, artesanal, funcionarial, militar... han nacido y expandido un número sin fin de palabras y voces nuevas que hoy en día utilizamos sin saber que se originaron allí.

Así que empecé por buscar en las notas de la misma Salamanca de principios del S. XX, tratando aquellas obras que intentaban recoger rasgos peculiares del habla y de los vocablos utilizados en el lenguaje sencillo desarrollado en determinados momentos por cuestiones que podían responder a la historia ó a la moda.

Así existieron autores como Unamuno entre otros, que recopilaron voces de esta región. Otros escritores, contribuyeron con el Vocabulario de Gatta y El dialecto vulgar Salmantino de Lamano y Beneite y el Vocabulario de Lamano de 1915, en ellos se hallan bastantes de estas voces sobre todo de Salamanca y León.

En estos libros que se recogen voces dialectales, es donde aparece por primera vez la voz "Mesingo" y la define como;

- **MESINGO** señorito de la ciudad delicado, afectado, presuntuoso, melindroso.

Aunque existen citas de otros escritores, se cree que el primero que recopilo la voz "Mesingo" al igual que otras que aparecen en los libros anteriores, fue, Luis Maldonado de Guevara y Fernández de Ocampo, ilustre personalidad Salmantina (1860-1926), recogiéndose por primera vez la voz en 1908.

A este respecto es muy bueno el trabajo que realiza Lourdes García Macho en la agrupación de todos estos datos y que ayuda a situar temporalmente la fecha en la que "Mesingo" es recogido en texto.

Para mi preocupación la voz "Mesingo", se complicaba, pues aparecía "Mesinga" en Esloveno con el significado de "Latón", aunque tenía mis dudas, tampoco era la primera vez que una voz alejada en el espacio llega a nosotros, también aparece la palabra Mesingo como uno de los dos cuarteles establecidos en Goito (Italia) durante las Guerras Italianas (1521-1526) entre España y Francia, pero no encontré nada. Al final ni el "Mesinga" Esloveno ni el Mesingo Italiano, parece que tenían que ver con el "Mesingo" Español.

Después de un periplo largo de análisis de datos. En el léxico de Luis Maldonado de María Lourdes García-Macho de 1989 aparecen, en la pag. 80, 445, y 446,  curiosas variantes.

- en la *Pag 80* encuentro; mesingo, mesinguin, misingo, misinguin
- en la *Página 445*; Mesenguin V. Mesinguin.

**MESINGO,GA**  sust . m . y f . ( salm . ) ' *señorito de la ciudad delicado , afectado , presuntuoso , melindroso ' : « Pero no es cosa de que malrote V. en una probe campesina el caudal que va a usted a necesitar priesto , cuando* ...

- en la *Página 446*;

**MESINGUIN,NA - MESENGUIN** - Sust. m. y f. (salm) Señorito de la ciudad, afectado, gomoso. " Y la chica...a pasear en la Plaza con el sombrerete, llevando a la cola a tóos los mesinguines de la ciuá" Cavila, 59, Lionardo, 84: 2v.: C y C; Vocaciones, ...

---

En Otro libro continuamos recopilando más información;

En El dialecto vulgar Salmantino: obra laureada con accesit de José de Lamano y Beneite · 1915

Mesinguin : K ... antes me dejaría emplumar que vestir un frac o una levita ; pero , por dentro , no cedo a ningún misinguín de la ciudad en cariño . » ( Maldonado .

- en la *Página 537*;

(Maldonado La Montaraza, pag. 21)

Mesinguín,na, adj. Mesingo:

"...nunca barruntara la mesinguina que trae lo que hemos sio"

- en la *Página 540*;

Miserioso, sa adj. Avaro

Misingo,ga adj. Mesingo

Misinguín,na adj. Mesinguín

Esto hace pensar que la voz "Miserioso" como adjetivo, podía ser parte inicial de la idea germinal que comportaba características achacadas a esas personas como seres avaros, miserables, mezquinos, basada en la palabra latina para esos calificativos, miser-a-um, mísero, miserable,  misere, miseria y que posteriormente se  desarrolló para incluir nuevos calificativos, como blandengue, delicado...que estaría en las palabras utilizadas en latín para los frutos del campo, mitigo, mitis-e, reblandecer, blando, suave y que darían la voz Misingo, Misinguín. Aunque la voz seguiría su evolución para incluir a "Mesingo" como el señorito blandito de la ciudad que se pasea y acerca afectado y gomoso a las chicas de forma melindrosa. Es de notar que la "i" y la "e", son fácilmente intercambiables en la región, pero, ¿en qué se baso el nuevo término?

---

Para no cansar al lector, en este proceso, en el que se puede observar como la voz "Mesingo" es simplemente la resultante más visible del proceso y variante de otras palabras que igualmente pueden utilizarse como sustitutas a ella significando lo mismo.

Recopilando todas las características de "Mesingo" se refieren especialmente a un tipo de persona con ciertas peculiaridades, alguien delicado, embaucador, afectado , presuntuoso , melindroso, señorito, ruin, vanidoso, codicioso....que puede vestirse con frac y levita...etc....

Entonces comprendí que "**MESINGO**" se trataba de un regionalismo Salmantino, evolucionado, como más arriba he expuesto, y que ahora se encontraba con la palabra, "Mesingo, utilizada para referirse a los "señoritos" de forma despectiva.

De esta manera por ejemplo, en España en general entendemos al decir "Señoritingos", para expresar exactamente la misma idea que "Mesingo" y en general comprendemos cuando alguien dice "Tiquismiquis" como persona delicada, fifi, melindroso, quisquilloso, relamido, remilgado, mezquino, codicioso....como parte de las características generales que puede tener un "Señoritingo". En Murcia, por otro lado, también tiene su propio regionalismo como voz y llama a este tipo de personas, "Churibitos".

De esta forma si "Señoritingos" es todo lo que tienen los "Mesinguines" y "Misinguines", "Mesingo", en singular. Señoritingo y Mesingo, seria la misma cosa.

- La pregunta siguiente sería;

¿ Saber, en la palabra evolucionada "Mesingo", donde habían basado los Salmantinos, el sentido de su expresión "Mesingo", como Señorito?.

En ese momento creo que lo vi claro, la evolución, el sinónimo "Misingo" "i", en "e" y la coincidencia, habían hecho modificar popularmente la palabra Francesa "Messieurs", como "Señoritos", pronunciado "Mesie" ó "Mesies" en Español castizo, y añadido el sufijo "**ingo**" que es desvalorativo y despectivo, utilizando la nueva formación, "Mes-ingo", "Mesingo", para añadir el calificativo de "señorito", al igual que cuando decimos Señoritingo ó un Misteritingo, ahora contábamos en este encuentro con "Mesingo" y "Mensiguin/na".

Por último recalcar que la variante en "i" como "Misingo ó Misinguín, es solo una forma alternativa de pronunciación de la zona regional Salmantina donde se cambia fácilmente la "e" por la "i" y viceversa, por ejemplo en la palabra "Gumisinda", en lugar de "Gumersinda", también indicar que la influencia Francesa en esta época de últimos del S. XIX y primeros de S.XX es notable en toda la región, de ahí que no me extrañe nada esa elección ó influencia, aunque debería tener más tiempo para recabar más datos sobre la sociedad de la época. Sin embargo y en general creo ha sido un estudio interesante y parece, al menos, que entre en lo probable. Espero que haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo al cien por cien con tu penúltimo párrafo y una respuesta tan larga podría enriquecerse con una referencia a la presencia francesa en Salamanca que por lo visto empezó en la edad media: https://www.lagacetadesalamanca.es/hemeroteca/francos-nuevo-francos-franceses-ORgs145469

Answer (score 0):

in English:

This website https://palabras.help/mesingo says the word mesingo is from Salamanca, and this other website https://www.britannica.com/place/Salamanca-Spain says Salamanca is a city in Western Spain.

en Español:

Este sitio web https://palabras.help/mesingo dice la palabra mesingo es de Salamanca, y este otro sitio web https://www.britannica.com/place/Salamanca-Spain dice Salamanca es una ciudad en el oeste de España.

Comment: @Sisifo I'm sorry, I apologize for misunderstanding. I thought "¿De dónde viene la palabra “mesingo”?" meant: "Where does the word "mesingo" come from?"

Comment: Salamanca, northwestern Spain.